# Multiple actions in redux observable epic based on rules

Tags: redux, react-redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I realize I can emit multiple actions in `redux-observable` `epic` and have seen a few examples but I can't seem to get it right in my case.

Basically, I want to return three actions that are NOT dependent on each other. However, each action will be based on a decision I have to make using some values in my state. So, it's something like this:

```
const doX = () => ({ type: types.DO_X });
const doY = () => ({ type: types.DO_Y });
const doZ = () => ({ type: types.DO_Z });
const doA = () => ({ type: types.DO_A });
const doB = () => ({ type: types.DO_B });
const doC = () => ({ type: types.DO_C });

export const myEpic = (action$, state$) => action$.pipe (
   ofType(types.SOMETHING_HAS_HAPPENED)
   mergeMap(action => Observable.of(
      const value1 = state$.value.module1.value;
      if(value1 > 10) {
          doX();
      } else {
          doY();
      },
      // Second action
      const value2 = state$.value.module2.value;
      if(value2) {
         doA();
      } else {
         doB();
      },
      // Third action -- similar idea here
   )
);
```

It's the block of business logic where it's not working. Also, I think I'm supposed to use `mergeMap` in this case but not 100% certain.

In this simple case, I could've easily done `if(state$.value.module1.value > 10)` but there are cases in my app where it's more readible for me to assign those values to local variables because I'm dealing with multiple values. So, it would be nice to create a nice block of code where I can clearly lay out my business logic.

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use the *expression* version of an arrow function in your `mergeMap` function. You can use an arrow function with a *body* and a `return` statement to return the new observable:

```
mergeMap(action => {

    const actionsToEmit = [];

    const value1 = state$.value.module1.value;
    if (value1 > 10) {
      actionsToEmit.push(actionCreatorX());
    } else {
      actionsToEmit.push(actionCreatorY());
    }

    // Second action
    const value2 = state$.value.module2.value;
    if (value2) {
      actionsToEmit.push(actionCreatorA());
    } else {
      actionsToEmit.push(actionCreatorB());
    }

    return Observable.of(...actionsToEmit);
  }
)
```

So it's just standard procedural code...

Comment: This looks so much cleaner. However, I'm unable to import/use `of`. It's `undefined`. According to this article (https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/), I import it by using `import { of } from 'rxjs';` in v6. Just checked my `package.json` and my version is `6.2.2`. Any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: Apparently, in `v6`, we just need this: `return of(...actionsToEmit);`. This fixed the issue. Thanks again for all your help. Much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
const epic = (action$, state$) =>
    action$.pipe(
           ofType(SOME_TYPE)
           mergeMap(val => empty().pipe(
              merge(state$.value.v1 ? of(creatorA()) : empty())
              merge(state$.value.v2 ? of(creatorB()) : empty())
              merge(state$.value.v3 ? of(creatorC()) : empty())
              )
           )
```

I would do something like this if I really needed dispatch few actions in one epic. Instead of `of` and `empty` you can return arrays `[creator()]` or `[]`. I have swallowed initial action in order to avoid an infinite loop. However, consider splitting it into several epics.